# Scala Annotation Inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection, annotations

In Scala, I have an annotation and a base trait with the annotation, but extending that class doesn't inherit the annotation:

```
scala> import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

scala> case class AnnotationClass() extends StaticAnnotation
defined class AnnotationClass

scala> @AnnotationClass trait BaseTrait
defined trait BaseTrait

scala> class InheritingClass extends BaseTrait
defined class InheritingClass

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[BaseTrait].typeSymbol.asClass.annotations.size
res1: Int = 1

scala> typeOf[InheritingClass].typeSymbol.asClass.annotations.size
res0: Int = 0
```

Is there a way to get the subclass to inherit the annotation of the parent?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible to my knowledge.  The only description of the scope of annotations in the docs reads:

> An annotation clause applies to the first definition or declaration following it. More than one annotation clause may precede a definition and declaration. The order in which these clauses are given does not matter.

This probably means an annotation applies *only* to the first definition following it.  Of course, you can make a helper method that checks the definitions on base classes:

```
def baseAnnotations[T : TypeTag] = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass.baseClasses.flatMap(_.annotations)
baseAnnotations[InheritingClass].size //1
```

Answer (score 3):

While extending a trait does not inherit annotations, extending an abstract class DOES cause the annotations to be inherited.